# Search each line of a datatable for a value

Tags: ajax, class, datatables, rows

I am using dynamic server side dynamic tables, and trying to search for example the forth column of each line of the generated table for a specific value.

I would like to add a class to any row that contains a specific string.

This is what I have until now:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var dataTable = $('#dynamic-table').DataTable( {
            responsive: true,
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            lengthMenu: [[250, 750, 1000], [250, 750, 1000]],
            order: [[ 3, "desc" ]],
            columnDefs: [ {
              targets: [ 0, 1, 2, 5 ], //"targets": 'nosort',// using class
              orderable: false
            } ],
              "columns": [
                { "searchable": true },
                { "searchable": true },
                { "searchable": true },
                { "searchable": true },
                { "searchable": true },
                { "searchable": true }
              ],
            ajax:{
                url :"php/ajax.php", // json datasource
                type: "post",  // method  , by default get
                error: function(){  // error handling
                    $(".dynamic-table-error").html("");
                    $("#dynamic-table_processing").css("display","none");

                }
            },

            "createdRow": function( row, data, dataIndex ) {                                

                // Add a class to the row
                var data = dataTable.columns( [4, 1] ).data();
                if (data[0]=='login failed'){               
                    $(row).addClass('bg-dark-red');
                }
            }

        } );


        $("table.dataTable .sorting").append('<i class="glyph-icon"></i>');
        $("table.dataTable .sorting_asc").append('<i class="glyph-icon"></i>');
        $("table.dataTable .sorting_desc").append('<i class="glyph-icon"></i>');

    } );
</script>
```

As you can see the variable data[0], gets the value of each row but keeps all the values of each line, like example1, example2, example3 etc, so cannot compare the data[0] variable with the given string eg "login failed".

Which method or code should I use?

Thank you

Comment: [datatable forum discussion](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/28998/add-class-to-cell-when-using-server-side-processing) may help

Comment: well on this post you sent me there is no info regarding my problem. Ok to color a tr or td is not a problem. The problem is to color a tr or a td depending the value of the actual td e.g. if we have <td>red</td> then load class="red" else if we have <td>blue</td> then load class="blue"

Answer (score 0):

I think `drawcallback` will work:

```
           "drawCallback": function(settings, json) {
     var data = dataTable.columns( [4, 1] ).data();
            if (data[0]=='login failed'){               
                $(row).addClass('bg-dark-red');
            }
            }
```

Put this in place of your `createdRow` section.

Comment: I used the drawCallback function according to your post, but no impact.

Comment: Can you try to `console.log` your `data` variable after this line to see if you're actually executing the function: `var data = dataTable.columns( [4, 1] ).data();`